# Power Apps: Displaying table row on a new screen

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I am new Power Apps, I have a SharePoint List, a Collection and items on my Table is indexed, I want when an user click on the any index, the item on that row(record) should be displayed  on a new screen. 
I have tried "On-click" it only navigating to the new screen but the items on the row is not displaying. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable using OnSelect: `Set(varSelectedRow, ThisItem.record`. Then display `varSelectedRow` on the next screen.